# Iphone 6 Landscape & Portrait Dimension Size?

Tags: iphone, size, landscape, dimensions, portrait

Hi i was wondering if anyone knows the dimension size of Iphone 6, Landscape & Portrait in pixels?

I am trying to design graphics for my App that i am currently developing and needed to know pixel size in landscaping mode for iphone 6.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone 6 - 1334 ×750 (326 PPI)
iPhone 6 Plus - 1920× 1080 (401 PPI)

For more information ...https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/display/